# Not able to substitute nginx environment variable in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nginx

I am passing endpoint of REST APIs as env variable during docker build of nginx and having spent 6 hours trying most of the suggestions, I have run out of things/patience to try.

nginx conf that I am substituting:

```
location /my-api/ {
    proxy_pass  ${api_url}/;
}
```

I am passing this value during docker build:

```
#base_url comes from system env 
docker build --build-arg base_api_url=$base_url
```

I am getting this value in my Dockerfile:

```
ARG base_api_url
ENV  api_url=$base_api_url

# This prints the value
RUN echo "api_url= ${api_url}" . 

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80

# this works
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template

# Initially following code was building and deploying docker image and url was hard coded. it was working
# COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
# Below will start the image but no REST endpoint configured
# CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

# To substitute the api url few of the many things I have tried.
# Non of the below, have been able to replace the env api_url with its value 
# Actually I don't know -- since /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not replaced at all

# CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst < nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
# CMD /bin/sh -c "envsubst < nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;' || cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

# Last status
CMD envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf should have api_url replaced:

```
location /my-api/ {
    proxy_pass http://theApiURL;
}
```

I have also tried specifically passing env variable like this:

```
CMD envsubst ${api_url} < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

and variations like using `tee`.

Any help/direction to get this resolved is appreciated.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you're trying to replace a value in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` with `${api_url}`? If so, perhaps use `sed` on the file before running `nginx` (recommend `ENTRYPOINT ["nginx",....]` too). So, something like `RUN sed -i "s|my-api|${api_url}|g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` ... @works_as_coded beat me to it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I typically do this outside of a Dockerfile, using sed, in a deployment script.

Here's an example:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
 # Deploys locally for dev work

 set -e
 export API_URL=www.theapiurl.com

 sed "s/api_url/${API_URL}/" nginx.conf.template > nginx.conf
 ...

 # run docker
 docker-compose build --no-cache
 docker-compose up -d
```

Of course you can set the environment variable however makes sense for your use case. I find this approach much more flexible than anything Docker provides.